# See whether sudo mode is on (password is cached) on the command-line prompt

Tags: command-line, sudo, password, prompt, ps1

I want to know whether it is possible to indicate on the command-line (ideally in the prompt), whether *sudo mode* is on.

By *sudo mode* I mean that I have already entered my password correctly once in this shell session and it has not expired yet but is still cached.

In other words, can I tell somehow whether the `sudo` command I'm going to run will ask me for my password or will use the cached credentials?

Comment: You could check the clock via `date` as the cached credentials will expire after 15 mins... Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/190311/sudo-credential-caching-on-by-default

Comment: @ElderGeek That way I don't know whether credentials are cached at the moment or not though, just whether any `sudo` command was running within the last 15 minutes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant check the clock when you first run a sudo command. Clearly they won't be cached anymore after 15 mins. expires. Sorry I don't have an answer for you. I suppose you could figure out something clever with a temporary prompt adjustment but it's hardly worth the trouble. You could just use `sudo -i` and you'd know you were superuser because your prompt would change to `#` from `$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a long time, I have been using

```
sudo -S true < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

You might try that, but a recent update seems to have broken that since I now get a segmentation fault.

You might try `sudo -n true 2> /dev/null` (no `-v`). That seems to be working for me without renewing the timeout.

You can execute this in your prompt in various ways including something like:

```
PS1='\u:\w$(sudo -n true 2> /dev/null && echo " : sudo :") \$ '
```

This depends on the `promptvars` option which is enabled by default.

Note that once the prompt is issued, the indicator isn't updated again. So if the prompt sits there until the timeout expires, it may indicate that `sudo` is active even though it's expired.

Comment: Your initial suggestion of `sudo -S true </dev/null 2> /dev/null` behaved exactly as expected on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install. With luck, no future updates will induce the segmentation fault you noted. *This is totally gonna fail at the worst possible moment, isn't it?*

Answer (score 2):

There is no command to directly show the remaining time for cached credentials, you would have to script it.

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115506/sudo-testing-for-credentials

```
sudo -nv 2> /dev/null
```

will give an exit value of 0 if the password is cached, you may be able to modify the script in that link or write your own.

Alternately the time stamps are stored in `/var/lib/sudo` so you could probably write a script to display or check the time stamp as well.

Comment: But `man sudo` says that `sudo -v` also resets the cache timeout to 15 minutes again - which means repeatedly polling that command leads to the credentials to never expire, right?

Comment: And `/var/lib/sudo` is empty for me, except for an empty subfolder `lectured`. There are no timestamps anywhere, even the modification and access times of those empty directories are months old.

Comment: I am not sure where Ubuntu stores the time stamp in this case. I suggest you file a bug report / feature request with Ubuntu but they will likely push it upstream.

Comment: Since one has to activate one's "sudo power" to see if the credentials have been cached, and that would update the cache, you can never see "how much time is left".

Comment: According to man sudo(5) "Time stamp file checks
sudoers will check the ownership of its time stamp directory (/var/run/sudo/ts by default) " https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html or you can write a script to check the log file and determine the time stamp